# Underclocking PiZero for power saving worth it?

Tags: power, pi-zero, underclocking

How much power does the PiZero consume on it's lowest possible cpu clock setting (underclocked)?
<s>(Let's say the only usb add on is a wifi dongle.)</s>
And... is it worth it?

Comment: What is your intended application? Is it battery powered? If saving electrical cost (not battery powered) there is no real benefit to be had. Earlier models were calculated to cost approximately $12 per year.

Comment: no application yet... but yes battery powered.. just getting ideas for mobile-like applications

Comment: The need for a WiFi dongle would probably make this a zero sum game. But, without a project, the tradeoffs are large unknowns. Also without a plan it would be hard to say a bigger battery would not be a better alternative.

Comment: from this reference: https://www.raspberrypi.org/blog/raspberry-pi-zero/#comment-1249148 80mA idling on a pizero (no dongle of course).  Let's take out the wifi dongle idea for the tests and see how low it can get....

Comment: Some tips [here](http://www.midwesternmac.com/blogs/jeff-geerling/raspberry-pi-zero-conserve-energy).

Comment: If you are talking about battery power, you shouldn't be using any sort of pi, period.  Get something based on a mobile (rather than AC-powered set-top-box) chipset with real power management and sleep/wake.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Underclocking modern ARM cores usually brings little benefit. While lower clock frequency (and perhaps lower core voltage) do reduce power consumption, a core clocked to the nominal frequency runs faster, meaning it spends less time in active state and more time in sleep, which is a more efficient* way of saving energy than permanently running underclocked.

I remember playing with clock settings on a Banana Pi under moderate load (video playback) and checking current consumption via `/sys/class/power_supply/`. Differences I observed were smaller than the measurement fluctuations.

(*) efficient in the sense that you still have full CPU performance available when you need it.

Answer (score 0):

• power measurement chart of the Pi-Zero: less than the RaspPi A version. 
https://plus.google.com/post/z13wuzkavtb1f3hnc224ifgq4oehi1mmg

Comment: Welcome to Raspberry Pi! Whilst this may theoretically answer the question, [it would be preferable](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/8259) to include the essential parts of the answer here, and provide the link for reference.

Comment: I believe the author of this blog article didn't underclock anything, he just compared power consumption of all the PIs under different load.

Comment: The document is no longer avai;able :(

Answer (score 0):

According to this [forum post](https://forums.raspberrypi.com/viewtopic.php?t=324988), fixing the CPU frequency at 600MHz (no more turboing to 1GHz) on a Pi Zero 2 W did save total consuming power:

> With default settings, a 4-core prime number benchmark took 413
> seconds to run, averaging 2.07W of power draw and in total consuming
> 0.237Wh of energy.
>
> With the underclock and undervolt, it took 691 seconds to run,
> averaging 1.06W of power draw and in total consuming 0.204Wh of
> energy.
>
> Thats an energy reduction of about 14%. It may be possible to do even
> better than this with a more aggressive undervolt.

These are the settings for the /boot/config.txt

```
arm_freq=600
arm_freq_min=600
over_voltage=-6
over_voltage_min=-6
```

WARNING: setting `over_voltage` and `over_voltage_min` to -8, disabled wlan0. Please caution while fiddling with these settings.